# How to point document library to a network drive when run Liferay as Window Service

Tags: windows-services, liferay-7, network-drive

I installed Liferay as a Windows service following [this tutorial](https://arvindm.com/2011/10/14/liferay-6-tomcat-as-windows-service/) .

After that I created a Network Drive 'D', I created a folder named 'document_library' in this drive D and updated `Advanced File System Store` to point to this folder. It work well when I run liferay from CMD window:

```
catalina.bat run
```

However, if I start Liferay by starting installed service, it throws exception: `Unable to create directory D:\document_library`
I tried adding full permission for `everyone` but still not solved yet.
How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have [this answer](https://community.liferay.com/forums/-/message_boards/message/110920065) . Followed him and it work.

Instead of using shared driver letter, we must use UNC path. Something like 
`\\server\share\path`